# Can I also use my US capital losses in Italy?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, italy

I’m a United States (US) citizen and a US resident and have been both my whole life. I have (1) US source capital loss carryover from previous years and (2) US source unrealized capital losses.

Let’s say I move to Italy, get my Italian citizenship by descent recognized, and become an Italian tax resident.

I understand I'd still have to file my US income tax returns, as long as I keep my US citizenship.

My question is about my Italian income tax returns. On those, could I offset my worldwide capital gains by 100% of the aggregate of my (1) US source capital loss carryover and (2) US source unrealized capital losses that I incurred prior to my becoming an Italian tax resident and that I realize while I’m an Italian tax resident?

Answer (score 4):

You should probably discuss this with both an Italian and a US tax professionals. Even better - someone who knows both, understands issues pertaining US expats in Italy, and is well-versed in the Italian-US tax treaty.

From my personal knowledge and understanding, I do not believe that you can have your tax benefit given by one country recognized by another.

As a US citizen, you will continue paying taxes in the US and filing tax reports, and will continue using the capital loss carryover in future years as you have until now. You will similarly get a tax benefit once unrealized capital losses are realized and show up on your US tax return. So there's no need to attempt to have the Italian government to recognize it - you're not losing it.

Comment: Also know as a US citizen (or LPR) you must annually _report_ other-country bank accounts over $10k on FBAR, and financial assets over a higher threshold on 8938 (if you file); compare https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/113238/us-capital-gains-tax-for-us-citizens-living-in-ireland-on-us-brokerage-stock-sal .